# checking if list is all numbers in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

so I have a program:

```
(defun add (L)
  (cond((endp L) nil)
       (t(cons(1+(first L)))(add(rest L)))))
```

that will add 1 to each member of the list. I want to check if the list is all numbers and return nil if not, and don't know how to go about doing that within the defun.

I thought of doing

```
(defun add (L)
  (cond((endp L) nil)
       ((not(numberp(first L))) nil)
       (t(cons(1+(first L)))(add(rest L)))))
```

but that will still return the beginning of the list if the non number is in the middle. How would I pre check and return nil at the beginning?

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap it in a `condition-case`

```
(defun add (L)
  (condition-case nil
      (mapcar '1+ L)
    (error nil)))
```

Comment: `condition-case` is in Emacs Lisp. In Common Lisp one would use `ignore-errors`.

Comment: @RainerJoswig thanks, it started out with emacs tag, I guess it got deleted

Comment: Not sure what dialect the question is about, though.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to use iteration:

```
(defun add (l)
  (loop for x in l 
     if (numberp x) 
     collect (1+ x) 
     else do (return-from add nil)))
```

The function is immediately exited with `nil` on the first non numeric element.

Comment: another option is to use `ALWAYS (numberp x)` and `COLLECT (1+ x) INTO l1 FINALLY (rerturn l1)`

Answer (score 3):

You would not implement iteration using recursion, since Lisp already provides iteration constructs. Example: `MAPCAR`.

Common Lisp also provides control flow constructs like `RETURN-FROM`, where you return from a *block*. A function defined by `DEFUN` has a block with its name and `BLOCK` can also create a named block explicitly. Examples for both:

```
CL-USER 62 > (block mapping
               (mapcar (lambda (item)
                         (if (numberp item)
                             (1+ item)
                           (return-from mapping nil)))
                       '(1 2 3 nil 5 6)))
NIL

CL-USER 63 > (block mapping
               (mapcar (lambda (item)
                         (if (numberp item)
                             (1+ item)
                           (return-from mapping nil)))
                       '(1 2 3 4 5 6)))
(2 3 4 5 6 7)
```

As function:

```
CL-USER 64 > (defun increment-list (list)
               (mapcar (lambda (item)
                         (if (numberp item)
                             (1+ item)
                           (return-from increment-list nil)))
                       list))
INCREMENT-LIST

CL-USER 65 > (increment-list '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
(2 3 4 5 6 7)

CL-USER 66 > (increment-list '(1 2 3 nil 5 6))
NIL
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that an idiomatic way, in Common Lisp, of checking that all elements in a list are numbers would be `(every #'numberp the-list)`, so I would probably write this as:

```
(defun add-1 (list)
   (when (every #'numberp list)
      (mapcar #'1+ list)))
```

It would be possible to use `(if ...)` or `(and ...)`, but in this case I would argue that `(when ...)` makes for the clearest code.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty is that propagating `nil` results in the `nil` at the end of the list causing everything to be `nil`. One solution is to check that `add` returns `nil` but `(rest xs)` is not `nil`. However, IMO it is more straightforward to just iterate over the list twice, checking for numbers the first time and then doing the addition on the second iteration.

Try this:

```
(defun add (xs) 
   (cond ((endp xs) nil) 
         ((not (numberp (car xs))) nil) 
         (t (let ((r (add (rest xs)))) 
                 (cond ((and (not r) (rest xs)) nil) 
                 (t (cons (1+ (first xs)) r)))))))
```

Barring mistakes on my end, this results in:

`(add '()) => nil`

`(add '(1 2)) => '(2 3)`

`(add '(x y)) => nil`

`(add '(1 2 y)) => nil`

EDIT: Without `let`. This results in `2^(n+1)-1` calls to `add` for a list of length `n`.

```
(defun add (xs) 
   (cond ((endp xs) nil) 
         ((not (numberp (car xs))) nil) 
         (t (cond ((and (not (add (rest xs))) (rest xs)) nil) 
                  (t (cons (1+ (first xs)) (add (rest xs)))))))))
```

Comment: Thank you that makes more sense. Is there a way to do this though without using let and defining the r variable?

Comment: Yes, but it has causes some unwanted problems. You can just replace `r` in the let body with `(add (rest xs))`. The problem is that this causes each level of the recursion to call itself twice, so you end up with an exponential number of calls to `add` at each level. In other words, with the `let`, a top-level call to `add` on `'(1 2)` results in a total of 3 calls to `add`, but this increases to 7 calls without the let binding. For a list of length 10, the corresponding numbers are 11 and 2047.

Comment: so on the `(t (let . . .` line you would just remove `(let ((r` and then replace the instances of `r` in the following code with `(add (rest xs))`? I've just started attempting to learn lisp and I'm still trying to grasp the syntax

Comment: Yes. I've added an edit to show the code without `let`, though I would say it is a bad idea even for "small" lists.